# Generating PL/SQL from SQL: Building a Dataset for Fine-tuning AI Models

Tags: sql, plsql, large-language-model, llama

I'm working on a project called "data structure and stored procedure from SQL to PL/SQL" which aims to develop a model that automatically translates SQL queries into corresponding PL/SQL code. This includes converting data structures and logic within stored procedures.

One of the biggest hurdles I've encountered is finding a suitable dataset to train my model. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a readily available dataset with paired SQL and PL/SQL examples that encompass the diverse scenarios I want to handle.

I'm seeking the community's expertise on the following:

Data acquisition strategies: Have you encountered similar challenges? What strategies have you used to build datasets for code-to-code translation tasks?
Alternative resources: Are there hidden gems in terms of code repositories or datasets I might have missed?
Data generation approaches: Could tools like synthetic data generation or code mutation be viable options for creating training data?
Model selection and fine-tuning: Are there specific models or fine-tuning techniques recommended for converting SQL to PL/SQL, especially for data structures and stored procedures?

Comment: Hi - 1) so what’s the single, well researched question you are asking? 2) while not wanting to dampen your enthusiasm, I’ll think you’ll find that the end result you are trying to achieve is not possible

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please read the guidelines *before* posting a question, especially the ones that talk about unfocused posts with many questions.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I’m curious about what it means to translate a query into PL/SQL code, since PL/SQL doesn’t really have output. What would be the PL/SQL equivalent of `select * from dual`, for example? How would that change for a join?

Comment: I agree with William Robertson. SQL and PL/SQL are two very different things. The first is a database query language while the latter is a programming language. It's like asking "I want to convert all my Word documents into Excel documents". It doesn't seem to make much sense on first glance.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson this is the equivalent of your example : DECLARE
    dummy_value VARCHAR2(10); -- Assuming the column type in DUAL table is VARCHAR2(10)
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    INTO dummy_value
    FROM DUAL;

    -- Use dummy_value variable here if needed
    -- For example, DBMS_OUTPUT to print the value
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(dummy_value);
END;

Comment: @KarimSliti While that is a common example used in tutorials, that code would almost never be used in production. DBMS_OUTPUT is useful for debugging but is generally not a reliable way to get information from the database; it is not enabled by default, even a moderate amount of such output can crash the session, the output can be "stolen" by other sessions, and many apps are terrible at retrieving it and formatting it. Before you start down this path of converting between languages (which certainly could be useful if done the right way!), you should look at use cases that provide real value.

Comment: @KarimSliti thanks for the example, but it seems to me to raise even more questions. What if there is more than one column, one row, or one table? But even when you have solved those technical issues you still haven't "translated a SQL query into corresponding PL/SQL code", you have added a wrapper to your original query that displays its output one row at a time in the form of debug messages. The query is still there, and your client tool (SQL Developer etc) would have displayed the output for you anyway, and made a better job of it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much more helpful to build a tool that converts PL/SQL into SQL instead of the other way around. In Oracle, a declarative SQL solution is almost always faster and smaller than a procedural PL/SQL solution. The most common mistake made by new Oracle developers is to create row-by-row PL/SQL solutions that could have been done in a single SQL statement instead. The best PL/SQL programs do the heavy lifting in SQL, and just use PL/SQL to glue the SQL statements together.

Overly procedural PL/SQL code limits the ways that Oracle can retrieve and modify data. Row-by-row code often forces the Oracle optimizer to choose sub optimal execution plans. Whereas putting everything in a SQL statement opens up a large number of transformations and better execution plan options. For example, in [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77977846/alternative-for-for-loop-pl-sql), converting a PL/SQL FOR loop to a single SQL statement INSERT gives Oracle the ability to choose many more algorithms to solve the problem.

Converting PL/SQL to SQL also seems to be an easier problem to solve than the reverse. When you start with PL/SQL, you have the procedural "what to do" solution. From that solution, you can extract the declarative "what is true" and turn it into a SQL statement that can be easily pasted into PL/SQL. But if you start with the "what is true" SQL, you don't necessarily know which direction the PL/SQL will go. Is that SQL going to be looped through to do something else, will it be used to update or delete from a table, etc. If you find the PL/SQL in DBA_SOURCE you could derive the SQL in GV$SQL, but not the other way around.

While I've probably seen a few hundred examples of converting PL/SQL to SQL in my life, I can't think of any easy way to find them all in a single data set. Some of the examples I've seen would be from books or blog posts that demonstrates the principles of writing set-based SQL instead of row-by-row PL/SQL. But those books or blogs would only give a few examples each. There are plenty of performance questions on Stack Overflow where best answer is "convert your PL/SQL to SQL", but the answers often don't offer a completely identical solution. Or even if they do, it's unlikely they will provide the test data need to verify the equivalence of the solutions. I've written probably a few dozen such answers on Stack Overflow, but even I have trouble finding them now.

Perhaps you'll have to painfully build this dataset yourself. You could start by gathering PL/SQL programs from a large number of databases just by getting all the data from DBA_SOURCE. Find a friendly DBA with access to hundreds or thousands of databases, and an automation tool to pull all the data together, and they could give you millions of lines of source code to play with. (Assuming you solve issues like rights to the code, anonymization, etc.) I've done that myself a few times for random Stack Overflow questions, but I don't have that access anymore. Then you could narrow down that data and identify potential PL/SQL to SQL conversion opportunities using tools like DBA_DEPENDENCIES or PL/Scope. Those examples would show you the "shape" of such interactions between SQL and PL/SQL, but then you'd have to build and test the training data yourself.