# Alternative for 'for loop' PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there any way I could possibly not use a loop in the following example.
The idea is to find a way that doesn't use a loop and slow down as much when I have
more data.
From the first table  param_tbl ,I take the parameters that have already been filled.
From the second table  result_tbl  i Gets the result based on parameters from the first table.
I insert the result   in the third table final_table_resul_tbl.
But using a loop I have too much delay.
I tried with  function 'WITH' and  Merge, but I didn't get the desired result.

```
    CREATE TABLE param_tbl (asset_id int, actual_date date  );

      insert into param_tbl (asset_id,actual_date)
      SELECT 1, DATE '2017-04-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 1, DATE '2019-02-25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 1, DATE '2020-03-13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 2, DATE '2017-11-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 2, DATE '2019-02-25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 3, DATE '2016-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 3, DATE '2021-10-21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 3, DATE '2022-10-19' FROM DUAL;
      

CREATE TABLE result_tbl (asset_id int,asset varchar2(30) , actual_date date  );
    
    insert into result_tbl (asset_id,asset,actual_date)
      SELECT 1,'Mixed',   DATE '2017-04-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 1,'Mixed'   ,DATE '2019-02-25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 1,'Mixed',   DATE '2020-03-13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 2,'Dividend Stocks' ,DATE '2017-11-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 2,'Dividend Stocks' ,DATE '2019-02-25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 3,'Large Cap Stocks' ,DATE '2016-12-31' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 3,'Large Cap Stocks', DATE '2021-10-21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 3,'Large Cap Stocks', DATE '2000-10-21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 3,'Large Cap Stocks', DATE '2001-10-21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      SELECT 3,'Large Cap Stocks' ,DATE '2022-10-19' FROM DUAL;
      
 CREATE TABLE final_table_resul_tbl (asset_id int,asset varchar2(30) , actual_date date );
 

   declare 
   cursor c1 is

 select   asset_id,actual_date from param_tbl;
        BEGIN

            
    FOR a IN c1 LOOP
  insert into final_table_resul_tbl(asset_id,asset,actual_date) 

              select  asset_id,asset, actual_date from   result_tbl
              where asset_id = a.asset_id and  actual_date = a.actual_date;
              END loop;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting a PL/SQL loop into a SQL join will often significantly improve performance and simplify the code:

```
insert into final_table_resul_tbl2(asset_id,asset,actual_date) 
select result_tbl.asset_id, result_tbl.asset, result_tbl.actual_date
from param_tbl
join result_tbl
   on  param_tbl.asset_id = result_tbl.asset_id
   and param_tbl.actual_date = result_tbl.actual_date;
```

The SQL version does not require context switches between SQL and PL/SQL engines. And the SQL version allows the optimizer to choose potentially faster execution plans for the join. For example, since there are no filters on the tables, it is likely that the optimizer will chose a hash join. Whereas the PL/SQL version is a hard-coded nested loops join. For a large amount of data, hash joins are usually significantly faster than nested loop joins.